# Django get content of an ModelChoiceField object

Tags: django

I want to get the attributes of an ModelForm. 
Actually I create an ModelForm(request.POST) object and then I use a for-loop to get fields of the ModelForm. But I only geht the referenc of this objects not the content. What can I do?

```
  forms = FormSet(request.POST, prefix='probe')
  for form in forms:
       form.fields['some_id']
```

With this code I get some stuff like this:

```
  <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x034705B0>
```

Do somebody now how I get the content of this object?

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: It looks like you want instead to be using the `cleaned_data` attribute of the form.  Once you've validated it, anyway.  You're getting exactly what you asked for - the field object - but from context I'm guessing that you're trying to get the chosen model instance, and that'll be in form.cleaned_data['some_id'].

Comment: I want to get the selectet option in the ModelChoiceField. Because I will save an m2m relation and not an new Object of the form in the database.

Answer (score 2):

```
if form.is_valid(): #validate the form
    cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
    print cleaned_data['some_id'] #print out the choice
```

Comment: When I print the choice, I dont get anything.

Comment: Okay I have find an problem they dont print because the data was not valid.. Next problem 'Form' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Comment: @user2457241 it only has cleaned_data if the form is validated.

Comment: @user2457241 nooo problem :-) Happy to help!